# jstree: how to start a jquery script by clicking an anchor

Tags: jquery, jstree

I try many things, but nothing works. Is there a way to run a jQuery script by clicking on a jsTree anchor?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.jstree-anchor > a').click(function() {
    var hidden = $('.index_right');
    if (hidden.hasClass('visible')) {
      hidden.animate({
        "right": "-1000px"
      }, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    } else {
      hidden.animate({
        "right": "0px"
      }, "slow").addClass('visible');
      hidden.css('display', 'block');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking, but perhaps the `select_node` event is what you are looking for:https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=select_node.jstree